# MVC3 with Razor - Avoid multiple javascript functions definitions on partial views

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, view, partial

We need to create multiple partial views of the same type, but this partial view has a javascript function. How can I avoid the definition of this function on each partial view? We don't want to define this function in another place.

Comment: You might also want to consider creating a reusable partial view.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend altering the solution to allow an extern javascript referece.  If this just cannot be done, then the following might work.  First I'll assume you're doing something like:

**/Views/Shared/MyModelPartial1.cs**/

```
@model MyModel

<script type="text/javascript">
  var a = "@Model.SomeStringProperty";
  var b = @Model.SomeNumberProperty;
</script>

<span>Some Html!</span>
```

**/Views/Shared/MyModelPartial2.cs**/

```
@model MyModel

<script type="text/javascript">
  var a = "@Model.SomeStringProperty";
  var b = @Model.SomeNumberProperty;
</script>

<div>Different Html Than 1</div>
```

If you're trying to share this Javascript between two Partials, then create another partial view that might look something like:

**/Views/Shared/MyModelJavascript.cs**/

```
@model MyModel

<script type="text/javascript">
  var a = "@Model.SomeStringProperty";
  var b = @Model.SomeNumberProperty;
</script>
```

**/Views/Shared/MyModelPartial1.cs**/

```
@model MyModel

@Html.Partial("MyModelJavascript", Model)

<span>Some Html!</span>
```

**/Views/Shared/MyModelPartial2.cs**/

```
@model MyModel

@Html.Partial("MyModelJavascript", Model)

<div>Different Html Than 1</div>
```

Comment: Actually, I have just one partial view. And it could be used in several  views. I think I'll take your recommendation to do it with a global/external file indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Move the definition of the `function` out of the partial and into a `global\external` JavaScript file:

**External JS**

```
function foo () {        
     /* ... code ... */
}
```

**Partial**

```
foo();
```

or (depending on how foo is defined you may want to create an instance of `foo`):

```
var bar = new foo();
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I've considered this, but I was wondering if are there another way to do it without an external file.

Comment: you could execute the code in an ***immediately executing function*** that encapsulates the variables of your function in it's own scope...